# TypeError: Cannot read property 'Mixin' of undefined

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to use ember-validation. I added validation.mixin in my controller , but it cause error. This is my controller code:

```
var loanController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(Ember.Validations.Mixin);
loanController.reopen({

borrowingLimits:null,
industries:null,
actions:{
submitAction:function(){
var model=this.get('model');
if (model!=null) {
var controller = this;
$.ajax({
type :'post',
async:false,
url : '/api/v1/loanapplication/',
data: JSON.stringify(model),
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}).done(function (data) {
controller.transitionToRoute('upload-documents',data);
});
}

}
}, 
validations: {
applicantFirstName: {
presence: true,
length: { minimum: 5 }
}
}
});

export default loanController;
```

how can I solve this problem?

**update**
I have added imports

```
app.import('vendor/ember-validations/packages/ember-validations/lib/core.js');
app.import('vendor/ember-validations/packages/ember-validations/lib/defaultMessages.js');
app.import('vendor/ember-validations/packages/ember-validations/lib/errors.js');
app.import('vendor/ember-validations/packages/ember-validations/lib/main.js');
app.import('vendor/ember-validations/packages/ember-validations/lib/mixin.js');
app.import('vendor/ember-validations/packages/ember-validations/lib/validatorNamespaces.js');
app.import('vendor/ember-validations/packages/ember-validations/lib/validators.js');
```

Comment: Did you include `ember-validation` before using it? It seems `Ember.Validations` does not exist. Did you import it?

Comment: What is the actual error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you might be incorrectly importing ember-validations but the root of the cause is that you're not importing the mixin into the controller file. The following will work.

**In your `Bower.json` file:**

```
{
  "name": "app-name",
  "dependencies": {
    "ember-validations": "http://builds.dockyard.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-validations/ember-validations-latest.min.js",
  }
}
```

Run `bower install`.

**In your `Brofile.js`:**

```
app.import('vendor/ember-validations/index.js');
```

**In `mixins/form-saving.js`:**

```
export default Em.Mixin.create(
  Em.Validations.Mixin, {

  // Your common form saving functions and properties
});
```

**In `controllers/loan.js`:**

```
import FormSaving from 'app-name/mixins/form-saving';

export default Em.ObjectController.extend(
  FormSaving, {

  // Methods and Properties here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the library?

Assuming you are using th ember-cli:

```
// in Brocfile.js after importing ember.js

app.import('vendor/path/to/ember-validations');
```

Comment: also in ember-cli I am not able to add folder,can import just file